# Which of these tensor product relations is correct?

Tags: tensors

I am reading Itskov on tensor analysis, and he has this equation for second order tensors (5.17):

$\textbf{A} \otimes \textbf{B} \textbf{:} \textbf{X} = \textbf{A}\textbf{X}\textbf{B}$

However, I am reading a [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6377211/) and the author uses (eqn 15):

$\left(\textbf{A} \otimes \textbf{B} \right)\textbf{:} \textbf{X} = \left( \textbf{B} \textbf{:} \textbf{X} \right)\textbf{A}$

Which is correct?  Is this an order of operations issue?  I don't believe it is because if we take the double dot product in Itskov's expression first, then we have a scalar with which to take the tensor product.